# Puppeteer: save PDF file in headless mode

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

What I want to achieve with headless chromium and puppeteer:

1. Login to some website
2. Navigate to pdf file
3. Download it to server

Headless chromium cannot navigate to pdf file, according to this bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=761295

So I've tried to get cookies from current puppeteer session and pass them with https.get request but unfortunately without success.

My code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://login-page', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
await page.type('#email', 'email');
await page.type('#password', 'password');
await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

// following line throws an error with headless mode
// await page.goto('https://url-with-pdf-accessible-only-after-login');

// I'm trying to convert cookie object to cookie string to pass it with headers
const cookies = await page.cookies();
let cookieString = '';
for (index in cookies) {
  const cookie = cookies[index];
  for (key in cookie) {
    cookieString += key + '=' + cookie[key] + '; ';
  }
}

// following code save me empty file (0 bytes)
const file = fs.createWriteStream('file.pdf');
https.get({
  hostname: 'host-with-pdf-file',
  path: '/path-to-pdf-accessible-only-after-login,
  headers: {
    'Cookie': cookieString,
  }
}, res => {
  res.pipe(file);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there any other way to save pdf file from url (which requires authentication) to server?

Comment: Could you try it with a library like [`request-promise-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native)? The first thing is to make sure you’re sending cookies in the correct format, which will be easier with the library. The second thing is to examine the HTTP request made when you manually download the PDF. Is there a `Referer` or a session ID or something in the headers?

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered almost the same problem.

INFO : i'm running this on windows 10 64 bits, node v8.9.4, puppeteer 1.12.2

MORE IMPORTANT INFO : doesn't work with the embedded "local-chromium" ( 73.0.3679.0 (64 bits) of puppeteer install) but work with installed Chrome !!! ( 72.0.3626.119 ), so i implement the custom "executablePath" properties for launch method :) and it works !!!

I search a couple of hours, so i wish that this solution can be usefull ...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  // Custom browser, headless not present Eq to true
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:/\Program Files (x86)/\Google/\Chrome/\Application/\chrome.exe'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  //URL
  await page.goto('https://www.theUrl', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.waitFor('input[name=NameOfTheLoginHtmlField]');
  await page.$eval('input[name=NameOfTheLoginHtmlField]', el => el.value = 'InputValueOfTheLoginHtmlField');
  await page.waitFor('input[name=NameOfThePasswordHtmlField]');
  await page.$eval('input[name=NameOfThePasswordHtmlField]', el => el.value = 'InputValueOfTheLoginHtmlField');
  //The submit button has been replaced by an "a" with js function behind, so ...
  await page.click('#login-submit > a');
    //Allow to define the download path ('' = current directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\72.0.3626.119)
    function setDownloadBehavior(downloadPath=''){
        return page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
            behavior: 'allow',
            downloadPath
        });
    }
  await setDownloadBehavior();
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  await browser.close();
})()
```

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS with recent Chromium version (82+) : no need to use 'executablePath' to point to Chrome.

Comment: Meaning : const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }); ?

Comment: Like in comment's code : without headless in await puppeteer.launch... means headless: true

Answer (score -1):

Could you using express.js to response pdf file?

> res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'example.pdf'));

**example.pdf** is a file generate from your server